# R: Handling error response in JSON format

Tags: r, json, rjsonio

I am requesting user details to the Facebook Graph API, such as

```
require(RJSONIO)
response <- RJSONIO::fromJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=Jack")
print(response)
# $Jack
# id       first_name           gender        last_name           locale 
# "534213341"           "Jack"           "male"      "Lindamood"          "en_US" 
# name         username 
# "Jack Lindamood"
```

All good.

But then sometime I have an error from the API to handle. Such as [this error response](http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up) (hope nobody will take this username...)

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

If I try to parse it with RJSONIO

```
RJSONIO::fromJSON("http://graph.facebook.com /?ids=this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up")
```

I get

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

But then If I first parse the json with `RCurl` I get the rjson-formatted error message

```
require(RCurl)
json <- getURL("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up")
RJSONIO::fromJSON(json)
$error
$error$message
[1] "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up"

$error$type
[1] "OAuthException"

$error$code
[1] 803
```

It is possible to manage the error directly with `RJSONIO`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
result <- try(RJSONIO::fromJSON("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up"), 
              silent=TRUE)`
```

and check `class(result)` before processing (it will be `try-error` if you get the error you posted).

You could also use the `httr` package (which directly uses a modern fork of the `RSJSONIO` package - `jsonlite`) vs the `RJSONIO` package:

```
library(httr)

content(GET("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=Jack"), as="parsed")
content(GET("http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up"),
        as="parsed")
## $error
## $error$message
## [1] "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: this.username.does.not.exist.because.i.made.it.up"
## 
## $error$type
## [1] "OAuthException"
## 
## $error$code
## [1] 803
```